# javascript form validation does not work and need to fix

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am doing class homework about form validation and  write some codes but they are not running at all. Can someone check it out what's wrong in them and fix?The first two functions are working properly. The problem is the third function formCheck for form validation does not work. If I put them in the same js document, the third function would also cause the other 2 functions to stop working.  Thanks
and this is the corresponding webpage working with the javascript:   http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~mintingt/jsvalidation.html

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("time").textContent = new Date();
}

  function changeColor(value)
{
    var color = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
    switch(value)
    {
        case 'lightpink':
            color = "#FFB6C1";
        break;
        case 'white':
            color = "#FFFFFF";
        break;
        case 'plum':
            color = "#DDA0DD";
        break;
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

   function formCheck()
{
  var form = document.getElementById("myform");
  if(form["first name"]== "") {
    alert("Please fill in the required first name.");
    form["first name"].focus();
    return false;
    }

 if(form["last name"]== "") {
    alert("Please fill in the required last name.");
    form["last name"].focus();
    return false;
    }

  var zip = /^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/;
  if(zip.test(form["zip code"]).value == false){
   alert("Please fill in a valid zipcode.");
   form["zip code"].focus();
   return false;
   }

  var phone = /^\[0-9]{10}$|^\([0-9]{3}\)[ ]?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
  if(phone.test(form["phone number"]).value == false){
    alert("Phone number input format is not valid.");
    form["phone number"].focus();
    return false;
    }

  var email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.])+@[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.([a-z])+$/;
  if(email.test(form["email address"].value == false){
    alert("Email format is not valid.");
    form["email address"].focus();
    return false;
    }

form.submit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You will be downvoted if you don't explain what is wrong. You can just simply post and say fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a parentheses `)` in:

```
if(email.test(form["email address"].value == false){
```

This is the error dump:

```
Timestamp: 30/04/14 18:20:25
Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after condition
Source File: http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~mintingt/validation2.js
Line: 32, Column: 53
Source Code:
  if(email.test(form["email address"].value == false){
```

Comment: The first two functions are working properly. The problem is the third function formCheck for form validation does not work. If I put them in the same js document, the third function would also cause the other 2 functions to stop working.

Comment: @user3563490 That is because it doesn't compile because there is an error: a missing `)` where I told you..

Comment: @user3563490 you have to add a `)` after .value